# WPF DataGrid, Grouping, and Scrollbar Sizing

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

So, I've recently come onto a project where they're using a standard .NET WPF DataGrid, using Grouping to build out several items underneath each respective group, and the scrollbar is acting very unusual.

I've noticed that it seems like it's getting confused about the size of the elements entirely.  It doesn't scroll via the pixel size of the elements -- it scrolls to the size of the Groupings, it looks like.  I don't know if there's an implicit style going on in the backend of the project, but I was wondering:

Is there a way to make the WPF DataGrid scroll by pixels of the total size and maintain that position, rather than aligning to the content via Groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` on your DataGrid. However, be aware that this will disable Row virtualization.

Comment: I have actually tried this, but it doesn't fix it.  The Scrollbar keeps changing size on the side (and position) -- and it seems to automatically align to the top of a data group...

Comment: Actually, our implicit style was screwed up and overriding the control template.  Just found it.  Adding this line in (since someone manually built the template for the DataGrid) to that implicit style (when it used to be CanContentScroll=true always, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Since .NET 4.5 you could use following to have nice scrolling with Virtualizing which improves performance: `EnableColumnVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" EnableRowVirtualization="True"`

`VirtualizingPanel` has even more interesting Properties to change